# A single word with the same meaning as: "Latest activity"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find a single word that would say "latest activity" or "most recent activity".

The word is to be used as a column header, and it will probably read either "latest activity" or "latest retry".

The column cells will hold time stamps that is stamped every time a state is changed or when a request to change state is sent. **It's really to identify idle workflows**.

I've tried searching for it but I don't seem to find any. Is anyone here aware of a single word that would communicate this?

Comment: I think it would be useful to know how you want to use this single word. A column header in a table, for example, might get a different choice from a word in a management report.

Comment: How about "latest" itself? Can you supply some context?

Comment: ELU just uses *activity*, which is sorted by "most recent first" by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a status timestamp you might use *Updated*.

The reason for asking about context is because if the column contained details of what the last activity actually was, it may have been appropriate to use something like *Progress*.

Comment: I like it! I think **Updated** will work great, thanks!